# Javascript Firefox errors

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a problem. I am trying to create some javasript, and it works perfectly in Google chrome, but when I tried to use it in Mozilla Firefox I am getting errors.

for example:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class");
x[0].innerHTML = 'some html code';
```

works perfectly in Chrome, but firefox returns this error in browser console:

```
TypeError: x[0] is undefined
```

also another problem:

```
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class2");
test.remove();
```

returns this error in Firefox:

```
TypeError: test.remove is not a function
```

everything works perfectly in Chrome, and in Tampermonkey for example.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: What happens when you do a `console.log(x)`?

Comment: HTMLCollection { length: 0 }

Comment: I get this in console with a lot of stuff to expand

Comment: add an element with the classname you mentioned in gEBCN to dom tree and try again. The function will return a classList not an array. You need to verify atleast one element with the class name is present in dom tree.

Comment: `TypeError: test.remove is not a function` this error is also returned by chrome. What you say seems to me a lie, because any reproduction of your code gives a different result from what you write

Answer (score 1):

I just tested on Firefox and it works perfectly, how do you get such a result?

```js
"use strict";

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class");
x[0].innerHTML = 'some html code';
```

```html
<div class="some_class">some_class 1</div>
<div class="some_class">some_class 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple.

The browser is telling you that x[0] **IS UNDEFINED** (doesn't exists) therefore it doesn't have a `innerHTML` property. Probably because the script is being executed before the elements with that class are in the DOM.

Try putting your script at the end of the document, before the `</body>` tag.

The second case is pretty much the same. It's the browser is telling you the test variable doesn't have a remove method.

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`. [HTMLCollection doesn't have a remove method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

You are probably trying to remove an element from that collection. In that case you can access that element like this `test[index].remove()`